# Convert object to time Pandas and filter between times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column containing a series of dtype'o' items:

```
0         17:32:16
1         17:32:20
2         17:32:24
3         17:32:28
4         17:32:32
5         17:32:36
6         17:32:40
7         17:32:44
8         17:32:48
9         17:32:52
10        17:32:56
11        17:33:00
12        17:33:04
13        17:33:08
14        17:33:12
15        17:33:16
```

how can I convert it into time in order to filter then between for instance 17:32:30 and 17:33:10?
At the Moment I was trying without success:

```
df_result['a']=datetime.datetime(df_result['a'], '%H%M%S').time()
```

any help? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create times by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) and then use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
from datetime import time

df_result['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df_result['a']).dt.time
df_result = df_result[df_result['a'].between(time(17, 32, 30), time(17, 33, 10))]

print (df_result)
           a
4   17:32:32
5   17:32:36
6   17:32:40
7   17:32:44
8   17:32:48
9   17:32:52
10  17:32:56
11  17:33:00
12  17:33:04
13  17:33:08
```

Another approach with `timedelta`s created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df_result['a'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_result['a'])
df_result = df_result[df_result['a'].between('17:32:30', '17:33:10')]

print (df_result)
          a
4  17:32:32
5  17:32:36
6  17:32:40
7  17:32:44
8  17:32:48
9  17:32:52
10 17:32:56
11 17:33:00
12 17:33:04
13 17:33:08
```